# Python beginner code for a currrency converter

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tkinter, unit-conversion

I am also pretty new to Python so I want to show my code for a very small currency converter with an Tkinter GUI.

The code does what I want, but now I want to optimize it and find new "next level" topics for me to learn. So I would be happy if some of you could take a look on my code and please give me constructive criticism.

Many thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def currency_converter():
    #creating instance of tkinter
    currency_converter = Tk()  
    #Set title of our window form  
    currency_converter.title("My First Tool - WOW")
    #Set dimension of form 
    currency_converter.geometry("425x225")
    #Centers the Window
    currency_converter.update_idletasks()
    w = currency_converter.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = currency_converter.winfo_screenheight()
    size = tuple(int(_) for _ in currency_converter.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
    x = w/2 - size[0]/2
    y = h/2 - size[1]/2
    currency_converter.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (x, y))) 

    currency_converter.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

    currency_converter.lift()

#    currency_converter.overrideredirect(1) #Remove border
    currency_converter.configure(background='#007780')

    def enter(event):
        UserInput = float(Currency_Input.get().replace(',', '.'))
        Currency_Output.delete(0,END)
        Currency_Output1.delete(0,END)
        Currency_Output2.delete(0,END)
        if box.get() == "EUR":            
            Currency_Output_Label.config(text="USD")
            Currency_Output.insert(0,round(UserInput*1.237203,2))
            Currency_Output1_Label.config(text="GBP")
            Currency_Output1.insert(0,round(UserInput*0.863629637,2))
            Currency_Output2_Label.config(text="CNY")
            Currency_Output2.insert(0,round(UserInput*7.76364208,2))
        elif box.get() == "USD":
            Currency_Output_Label.config(text="EUR")
            Currency_Output.insert(0,round(UserInput*0.808274794,2))
            Currency_Output1_Label.config(text="GBP")
            Currency_Output1.insert(0,round(UserInput*0.698050067,2))
            Currency_Output2_Label.config(text="CNY")
            Currency_Output2.insert(0,round(UserInput*6.28594776,2))
        elif box.get() == "GBP":
            Currency_Output_Label.config(text="EUR")
            Currency_Output.insert(0,round(UserInput*1.15790376,2))
            Currency_Output1_Label.config(text="USD")
            Currency_Output1.insert(0,round(UserInput*1.432562,2))
            Currency_Output2_Label.config(text="CNY")
            Currency_Output2.insert(0,round(UserInput*9.0008486,2))

        elif box.get() == "CNY":
            Currency_Output_Label.config(text="EUR")
            Currency_Output.insert(0,round(UserInput*0.128805526,2))
            Currency_Output1_Label.config(text="USD")
            Currency_Output1.insert(0,round(UserInput*0.159085,2))
            Currency_Output2_Label.config(text="GBP")
            Currency_Output2.insert(0,round(UserInput*0.111100636,2))

    def close_currency_converter():
        currency_converter.destroy()

    Headline_Label = Label(currency_converter, text='Currency Converter', bg='#007780', fg='white',font=("Century Gothic",16))
    Headline_Label.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

    Box_Headline_Label = Label(currency_converter, text='Which Currency?', bg='#007780', fg='white',font=("Century Gothic",11))
    Box_Headline_Label.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

    box_value = StringVar() 
    box = ttk.Combobox(currency_converter, textvariable=box_value, width=10)
    box['values'] = ('EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'CNY')
    box.current(0)
    box.grid(row=1,column=1, pady=5, sticky=E)

    Currency_Input = Entry(currency_converter)
    Currency_Input.grid(row=1,column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

    Currency_Input.bind('<Return>',enter)

    Currency_Output_Label = Label(currency_converter, text='', bg='#007780', fg='white',font=("Century Gothic",11))
    Currency_Output_Label.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

    Currency_Output1_Label = Label(currency_converter, text='', bg='#007780', fg='white',font=("Century Gothic",11))
    Currency_Output1_Label.grid(row=3,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)   

    Currency_Output2_Label = Label(currency_converter, text='', bg='#007780', fg='white',font=("Century Gothic",11))
    Currency_Output2_Label.grid(row=4,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)  

    Currency_Output = Entry(currency_converter)
    Currency_Output.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

    Currency_Output1 = Entry(currency_converter)
    Currency_Output1.grid(row=3,column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

    Currency_Output2 = Entry(currency_converter)
    Currency_Output2.grid(row=4,column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

    Button(currency_converter,text="Quit",command=close_currency_converter).grid(row=6,column=0, sticky=E+S+W, pady=5, padx=5)

    currency_converter.mainloop()

currency_converter()
```

Comment: Is this running slowly and needs to be faster? If not you might consider dropping the `performance` tag; also add a `beginner` tag.

Comment: I think the performance is ok. I droped performance and added beginner to the tags. Thank you!

Comment: You may consider [tkinter best practices](https://www.begueradj.com/tkinter-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## pep-8

Try to follow the Python styleguide, and above all, be consistent. Now you use a mix between `CamelCase`, `snake_case` and `Camel_Snake`

## imports

try to avoid `from xxx import *`. This pollutes the namespace and makes it unclear where certain variables or functions come from

## hardcoding values

You hardcoded the relative values of the different currencies. What if after a few days the exchange rates differ? Then you'll have to track this manually over your whole file. Easiest would be to keep 1 dict with the relative ratios, or 1 dict with nested a dict per currency

something like this:

```
CURRENCIES = {
    'EUR': {
        'USD': xxxx,
        'GBP': xxxx,
        ...,
    },
    'USD': {
        'EUR': xxx,
        'GBP': xxx,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

The added benefit of this is you can use the keys of this dict to populate the comboboxes

## main guard

put the calling of the main function behind `if __name__ == '__main__:`, so this code can be imported in other places too.

## separate the logic

I would separate the calculation and the presentation.

### calculation

The calculation can be just:

```
def convert(source, destination, amount):
    return amount * CURRENCIES[source][destination]
```

If you want, you can refactor this into a class, with the currencies passed into it as argument for the `__init__`

### Presentation

For the GUI I would make a class, that gets populated in the `__init__`, where the values of the important input fields and comboboxes are properties, and pushing buttons or other actions trigger different functions

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything from you answer helped me a lot. I have just one request remaining: **If you want, you can refactor this into a class, with the currencies passed into it as argument for the __init__** could you please provide me an example? I found some, but in didn't really get the idea of __init__,